# Can anyone explain this simple Javascript behaviour?

Tags: javascript

```
function cat() {

    this.Execute = new function() {

            alert('meow');

    }

}

var kitty = new cat();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaDxk/1/

Why does it do that? I haven't told it to run the function.

Comment: Your CamelCasing is inverted.  Classes should be UpperCamelCase; everything else should be lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `new function() { ... }`, you're creating an anonymous function, then calling it immediately in a `new` expression.
The result of this expression is an object—an *instance* of the class created by the anonymous function.

It's equivalent to

```
var anonymous = function() { ... };
this.Execute = new anonymous;
```

Comment: If that were true, you'd be able to call it again - but kitty.Execute isn't a function if you try to call it again.

Comment: @SLC: No.  `Execute` isn't a function; it's the object from the `new` expression.  The function is anonymous; the only way to call it again is to write `kitty.Execute.constructor()`.

Comment: I see, so it's an object, makes sense! :)

Answer (score 4):

Anonymous function with alert in it is used as constructor (because of `new`). `this.Execute` then becomes "instance" of this function object.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the use of "new".

if  you only want to assign the function and call it later, then you need to use it like this:

```
function cat() {

    this.Execute =  function() {  
            alert('meow');    
    }    
}

var kitty = new cat();
kitty.Execute();
```

when you use new in this context, your function behaves as if it is the constructor..